# Failing to call WCF Service

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF Service being hosted on IIS 5.1 with Anonymous access disabled. Below is a part of the web.config file showing how the service is configured:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="basicHttpBindingCfg">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="HelloService">
         <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndpoint" 
             address="" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingCfg"
             contract="IHelloService">
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Every time I call any operations that this service exposes from a desktop application, I receive the following error message:

> Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the
>   provided impersonation level is invalid.

Please note that binding type and hosting environment is pre-determined by the client and cannot be changed.

Any help that may lead to resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Zen

**EDIT:** Here is how the client is configured:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndpoint" 
          address="http://vm00000033871b.intra.pri/WCFServiceBasicHttp/HelloService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint"
          contract="Proxy.IHelloService" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How are you calling the service, are you passing network credentials for Windows auth?

Comment: @TheCodeKing, here is how I call the service: `Using proxy As New PRX.HelloServiceClient() Dim message As String = proxy.Hello("Hi") MessageBox.Show(message) End Using`. I am not passing any network credentials as the property ClientCredentials of the client is a ReadOnly property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to pass the current users Windows credentials:

```
Using proxy As New PRX.HelloServiceClient()
    proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
                                       TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation
    proxy.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
                                       CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    Dim message As String = proxy.Hello("Hi")
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Using
```

Comment: with these changes I am getting the following error message: The requested service, 'http://localhost/WCFServiceBasicHttp/HelloService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
Trace logs indicate that the service could not be activated because: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service. Btw. thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/03/23/preventing-anonymous-access.aspx). I'd start by removing the mex binding and getting it to work with http.

Comment: You did it!!! Thank you very much. I appreciate your help very much indeed. Have a good night.

Zen